# Bootstrap scrollspy is not working on appearing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a checkbox and when that specific checkbox is checked it shows some text above:

```
 $('#pck-94').click(function() {
     $('#pico-info').toggle(this.checked);
  });
```

this wil toggle the text which works and than I wanted to set a scrollspy which scrolls to the text which appears when checkbox is checked here is the html:

`<span id="pico-info">(het verjaardagsfeestje Pico Patat is voor kinderen vanaf 4 jaar en maximale lengte 1.30m)</span>`

and this is the scrollspy code where the checked is never logged:

```
   if($('input#pck-94').prop('checked')){
        console.log('check');
        $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#pico-info' });
    }
```

Here a fiddle : [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/yrk0xatt/2/)

Comment: can you please put your code to see issue?

Comment: Edit my question added a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yrk0xatt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how `scrollspy` works.

> Bootstrap scrollspy is a navigation mechanism that automatically highlights the nav links based on the scroll position to indicate the visitor where they are currently on the page.[1](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-scrollspy.php)

What you are looking for is to animate body scroll to a desired position.

Try this instead.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo:**](https://jsfiddle.net/4txn2kye/)</kbd>

```js
$('#pck-94').click(function() {
 $('#pico-info').toggle(this.checked);
});

$('input#pck-94').change(function(){
 $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#pico-info').offset().top
 }, 900);
});
```

```css
html,body{height:2000px;}
 #div1{height:1200px;}
  #chk{position:absolute;top:50px;left:200px;}
 #pico-info{display:none;}
 #div2{height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1">
 <div id="chk">Click Me: <input id="pck-94" type="checkbox" value="Show Pico-Info" /></div>
</div>
<span id="pico-info">(het verjaardagsfeestje Pico Patat is voor kinderen vanaf 4 jaar en maximale lengte 1.30m)</span>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Huh what why is it explained like what I did on bootstrap site?

Comment: And how do I change the offset?

Comment: Just add or subtract like this: `scrollTop: $('#pico-info').offset().top -200` See [this updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/4txn2kye/1/)